# Fire Observer for any page request within Magento 2?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.1

> Actually in my case i want to run observer which would just work like
>   index.php bootstrap initialisation file.
>
> Here I want here it should be work for each page request within Magento 2.
>
> Please guide me thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below event:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="page_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Page" />
</event>
```

Create **events.xml** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

with above content.

And create the class file with name **Page.php** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Page.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace Vendot\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Page implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Above code executes for all frontend pages.